Secure session cookie usage and Chrome
I noticed this message

Chrome blocks all third-party cookies from sites you visit, including
related sites. Send “Do not track” request with your browsing traffic:
When you toggle this on, you request that sites not track you.

What does it mean in practice for my system? I have three applications:

A monolith web application in Java EE, the UI code is using GWT.

An Angular application too.

An REST API service in Spring Boot.

All of the above applications are deployed in the same kubernetes cluster.


The GWT UI loads the Angular application via iFrame:
<iframe id="angular-app-id" src=<angular-app-url> .../>

Both GWT and Angular frontends need to talk with the REST API (spring boot) application.
At runtime, once a user logged in via the REST API application, the application response to frontend (GWT and Angular) the session cookie (flagged Secure; HttpOnly), all the subsequent requests from frontend are expected to contain this session cookie, which is browser's behavior if I am not mistaken.
So, my questions:

Will Chrome block this secure session cookie mechanism in my system?

Would Chrome block my cookie usage if Angular application and GWT application are deployed in different subdomain of DNS.



you can set the cookie for the main domain (instead of leaving it blank) and it will also be sent to subdomains.  I believe only if you set the cookie specifically for the subdomain (or leave domain blank) will it be treated as specific to that subdomain.  The iframe may inherit it's ancestor's domain for some rules.... but that shouldn't affect anything here.   The "3rd Party" bit is controlled via "same-site" attribute.... if set "strict", a link, say from google's search results, will not send that cookie with the request to your domain.

The "Do Not Track" request is really nothing but telling a web site "please don't track me".  They can ignore that if they like.  If you'd like to obey this, just be sure you don't set any 3rd party cookies.  (cookies that are set from domains other than yours... like from a google ad or some other embedded content)

@browsermator, thanks! Just to be sure, when you say "you can set the cookie for the main domain (instead of leaving it blank) and it will also be sent to subdomains.", do you mean my server will be able to send the session cookie to the subdomains? Or do you mean the subdomain sites are able to send request with the cookie to my server? Which one do you mean?

the user-agent (i.e. browser) will send it along with requests to your subdomains.   To clarify more, if you set a cookie from a subdomain and leave the domain bit blank, it will be set for the subdomain and subdomain only.  If you set it explicitly to the main domain it will work for domain and any subdomains.

I just learned I'm incorrect there... if you leave it blank it will still be sent to the current domain.  (so include domain and all subdomains)  The "_host" prefix can be used to restrict it to a specific subdomain:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#cookie_prefixes

No it's not possible
Workarounds:

A quick redirect to the other sites with an encrypted query string, containing the session id.

Make an API call (or even just call a page of the site) to each of those sites with a cookie using ajax upon login, and that site can return its own cookie


